# Maven dependencies doesn't get exported into the jar

Tags: java, maven, build, compilation, dependencies

I have a project which I want to export as jar (for some reasons it's impossible to export it as a runnable jar). I have 3 maven dependencies, `gson`, `io` and `junit`, but when I execute the maven built jar in console it says this:

[image]

Check my build path:

[image]

I export it this way (Eclipse):
Run as -> Maven build...

```
(mvn) package
```

And here is my pom:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Carlos</groupId>
  <artifactId>Buscaminas</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Buscaminas</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>res.application.Main</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Also the maven build result:
[image]

Comment: It is not clear but most likely you should update your manifest-file with the classpath definition which points to that lib directory you are putting your jar files. Can you share also your manifest file if exist?

Comment: I normally build uber-jar (containing dependencies) with `maven-shade-plugin`.

Comment: @cool No, it's seems to not be any manifest. I did a mvn clean install but still didn't appear.

Comment: But from your screenshot I thought you are not using maven to generate the jar. instead you are using jar exporter from some ide. So you should not use mvn clean install to check it. you should export the jar as you did before. If you want to make it run with mvn clean install you should use maven-shade-plugin or smth.

Comment: @cool So i add [this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html) to the pom and then i execute mvn package?

Comment: First keep the convention over configuration in Maven which means remove the configuration for `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` and keep your source in `src/main/java` and your unit tests `src/test/java` ...remove the resources configuration and keep your resources into `src/main/resources` which should be packaged into the resulting jar and for the unit test put the resources into `src/test/resources`...Removed maven-dependency-plugin from your configuration and add the maven-shade-plugin to your configuration if you like to make an executable jar file...

Comment: @khmarbaise I followed your steps and I updated the post.

Comment: So now you need to add the maven-assembly-plugin or the maven-shade-plugin to create the ueber jar file which contains all dependencies....https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My project didn't seem to have the correct project structure so I crated a new (maven) project and migrated my packages to the src/main/java folder and then used this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-my-bundle</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>res.application.Main</mainClass> <!-- Or wherever is your main method-->
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And executed `mvn package`

That created a "jar-with-dependencies" jar also with all the recources (images, interface fxml files...).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand what you need might be this one

```
mvn install dependency:copy-dependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

The built jar does not contain the dependencies, you must either provide them in classpath when executing the jar or have build process copy them into your jar, creating a so-called uber-jar. Good way to achieve the latter is using [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).